# How to obtain positions of graphs satisfying certain conditions?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, filtering

I first generate some random graphs, and then the following code can filter graphs with maximum degree 8.

```
glist= Table[RandomGraph[{10, 25}], {i, 1, 10}];
Select[glist, Max@VertexDegree[#] == 8 &]
```

But now I want to see the positions of the filtering graphs in `glist`. It seems  'Position' is ok, but I lost in many times.

```
Position[glist, Max@VertexDegree[#] == 8 &] (*always nothing*)
```

```
Position[glist, x_ /; Max@VertexDegree@x == 8]
```

The second did produce results, but it also gave an error warning.

[image]

Comment: `Position[glist, _?(Max@VertexDegree@# == 8 &)]` . You are almost there.

Comment: The second form should be: `Position[glist, x_Graph /; Max@VertexDegree@x == 8]`. It is because it is expecting a `Graph` object and `x` is a general pattern object.

Comment: Nice. You can write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first form requires [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) as `Position` requires a pattern for matching.

As opposed to this the [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) command requires a function that operates on elements to return a `True` or `False` value.

Parentheses are important.

```
Position[glist, _Graph?(Max@VertexDegree@# == 8 &)]
```

---

The second attemp using [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) requires a `Graph` object for which the `VertexDegree` function can be executed without warning. The correct form is:

```
Position[glist, x_Graph /; Max@VertexDegree@x == 8]
```

---

*Result:*

Depending on `SeedRandom[]`, the positions of `Graph` objects matching the stated criteria about the `VertexDegree` will be returned. E.g.,

```
{{5}, {9}}
```

Comment: Your first one also shows a warning on my computer (Mathematica 13.3).  `Position[glist, _Graph?(Max@VertexDegree@# == 8 &)]` is well.

Comment: Thanks for the accept and the heads up. I have updated the answer.